# TortoiseSVN 1.7.9: where is diff for merge?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I have a new TortoiseSVN (V 1.7.9), and now the merge dialog is without any diff option.

What I want is to see all diff's between my branch and trunk, before I do the merge.

If you look at an older screenshot, there is a diff button: 
http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2008/06/03/quothow-toquot-svn-merge-with-tortoisesvn.aspx

Is there any new way to do that?

And yes, I know how to do that on command-line, but I need it explicitly for TortoiseSVN.

Edit: See the screenshot of the merge dialog - there is no diff function: [image: tortoise merge dialog]

Test merge is just a check if there are merge conflicts, there is no diff between branches as in older versions. And I tested the "Show log" button as well - this is only a log list of the selected branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This diff ability is no longer within the Merge workflow.  Instead, you can do this:

1. From the Repo Browser...
2. Right-click -> *Mark for comparison* on the branch
3. Right-click -> *Compare URLs* on the trunk.

This will trigger the [Comparing Folders](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html#tsvn-dug-compare-revs) situation described in that documentation (which is the same thing that appears when *comparing revisions* from the SVN Log.
[image]

---

Another option:

1. Access the working copy of your branch.
2. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while right-clicking on the branch folder to be compared.
3. Select TortoiseSVN's *Diff with URL* option.
4. Specify the URL of the trunk to diff against.

If you're doing this on a folder then you're going to get TortoiseMerge's *unified diff* viewer, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

right click on folder and select

TortoiseSVN -> Settings

in settings click on diff viewer and set your favourite merge tool like winMerge or BeyondCompare

Comment: This didn't change anything.